# Quote inside input html (using PHP)

Tags: php, html, input, quote

I have something like this (code simplified):

```
<?php
    $var = 'Read "The Book"';
?>

<input type="text" value="<?php echo $var; ?>" />
```

The problem is that in the input looks like if it prints `read` and when you look at the source code you see it has `<input type="text" value="Read "The Book"" />` and it doesn't work.

I can't simply replace `value="<?php echo $var; ?>"` for  `value='<?php echo $var; ?>'` because `$var` could has any value and if I do it that way and its value is `D'Artagnan` it is going to try to print `<input type="text" value='D'Artagnan' />`.

=(

Any suggestion?

Comment: `<?php echo htmlentities( $var ); ?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should sanitize all your output by escaping characters with special meaning into their respective HTML entities. You can do that in the html context with `htmlspecialchars`.

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($var); ?>" />
```

So, with that, you can avoid XSS attack.

Comment: True that, completly forgot! Thanks.